# Safari browser only throwing this Jquery error div[id^='divSelectAll'] input[id^='chk_'")

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have below code which working in all browser but not on safari.

```
 $("div[id^='divSelectAll'] input[id^='chk_'").prop('disabled', true);
```

> it gives Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   div[id^='divSelectAll'] input[id^='chk_'

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the final closing square bracket `]` on your selector. Some browsers apparently handle this just fine, but Safari appears to be picky.

```
$("div[id^='divSelectAll'] input[id^='chk_']").prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: good catch.. thank you. I am confuse other browsers ignored this.